# Docker pull no progress bar on windows

Tags: docker, boot2docker, git-bash, mintty

on linux machine, or when I connect to boot2docker VM using putty, I can see this nice progress indicator when I'm pulling images:

```
1491ff176f58: Downloading [===========================>                       ] 1.481 GB/2.721 GB
```

Unfortunately when pulling exactly the same image from **Git Bash** (MinTTY) on Windows

```
git version 2.5.3.windows.1
```

docker version:

```
Client/Server: 1.8.2
```

There is no progress bar.

Any idea why?

Comment: I have the same issue with docker-toolbox v1.9.0, this should be a bug in docker-machine

Answer (score 0):

Docker Toolbox 1.8.3+ has workaround for this issue:

```
NOTE: When using interactive commands, prepend winpty. Examples: 'winpty docker run -it ...', 'winpty docker exec -it ...'.
```

See:
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/v1.8.3/windows/start.sh

For me it renders the progress bar, but it prints each state of progress bar as new line (not replacing lines like in ssh session).

**UPD:**

In Docker Toolbox v1.9.0c this issue has been fixed:

> On Windows, use bash and the default terminal for the Docker
>   Quickstart Terminal instead of mintty. This fixes several bugs causing
>   cannot enable tty mode on non tty input or repository name component
>   must match "a-z0-9*(?:[._]a-z0-9*)*".

Comment: Thanks, this works as you say, but only for images from docker hub, when pulling from private registry I always get: repository name component must match "[a-z0-9](?:-*[a-z0-9])*(?:[._][a-z0-9](?:-*[a-z0-9])*)*"

Comment: @vehovmar, try to update to 1.9.0.c, both issues should be fixed.

Comment: Sadly still the same problem on 1.9.1

Answer (score -1):

Some servers are providing info about the full size of the downloaded file. In this case you get a progress bar. Some servers are just streaming this data without size info, in this case docker can't show the data.

This is not a bug, this is a feature :) :)

Comment: That would be understandable. But I'm talking about situation when the server is providing info about image size. And when pulling on linux machine I'm able to see it, but not under MinTTY Git Bash on Windows.